# How long time is needed for "stay" to turn into "live"?

Tags: word-meaning

How long time is needed for "stay" to turn into "live"?

> I stayed there for five days
>
> I stayed there for three weeks.
>
> I stayed there for one month.
>
> I stayed there for two months.
>
> I stayed there for half a year.
>
> (Or "I lived there for half a year."?)
>
> I lived there for one year.
>
> I lived there for two years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice of verbs such as **stay, live, reside** is personal to the speaker.

**Stay** is generally considered to describe a briefer period somewhere that the speaker does not consider a permanent home - but there are many exceptions to this understanding.

**Live** and **reside** are used to describe situations that the speaker regards as more stable and permanent. But again there are numerous exceptions.

People are more likely to say **I stayed with a friend in London for several months** and **I lived with my partner in London for several months**. Much depends on the context.

So, in short, there is no simple answer to your question. Within the guidelines above, it's up to the speaker or writer to decide which verb fits best.

Where one may prefer **live** to describe a short stay, another may well choose **stay** to describe a much longer one.

Comment: When I worked for the Social Security administration in my country, a person receiving benefits could have someone to "stay" for two weeks. Any longer and they were deemed to be living there in a "joint household" for benefit calculation purposes.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey :I was going to mention that. In England, if you ask somebody "Where do you stay?" that can only be interpreted as habitual (eg "Where do you stay when you visit London?"), since the question about your current temporary residence would be "Where are you staying?". BUt for many Scots, "Where do you stay?" is a normal question, the equivalent of "Where do you live?" in England.

Comment: In some parts of Scotland people say "stay" in situations where standard English would use "live", e.g. "I have stayed here for two years so far".